# Intervene template rendering

Tags: twig, symfony4

I have a controller method which I am using to "collect" variables to be assigned to template. I have overridden controller's render() method to merge "collected" and render parameters and assign them to template.

Example:

```
class Controller extends \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller
{
    private $jsVars = [];

    protected function addJsVar($name, $value)
    {
        $this->jsVars[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function render($view, array $parameters = [], Response $response = null)
    {
        return parent::render($view, array_merge($parameters, ['jsVars' => $this->jsVars], $response);
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // collect variables for template
        $this->addJsVar('foo', 'bar');

        return $this->render('@App/index.html.twig', ['foo2' => 'bar2']);
    }
}
```

I just upgraded to Symfony 3.4 which complains that since Symfony4 I am not allowed to override render() method as it will be final.

How could I make it work seamlessly, i.e without defining a new method?

- I know about Twig globals but these dont help me
- I could use a service to collection variables and inject that service to Twig but that seems odd
- Are there events I could listen, e.g TwigPreRender or smth?

Comment: You could define your own render method, e.g. `renderWithJsVars(...)`. It would also serve as a form of documentation.

Comment: Yes but how can I use the same method. Edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that there is no easy way.

Basically there are 2 options:

- create your own template engine by extending current Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine
- decorate current templating engine service `templating.engine.mytwig`

I chose the latter.

Few explanations:

- I created service `templating.engine.mytwig` which [decorates](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html) current engine `templating.engine.twig`. Class will get current ´TwigEngine` as input and I'll delegate most of the stuff to it
- The class also needs to be [twig extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) by implementing `\Twig_ExtensionInterface` (or extending `\Twig_Extension` was sufficient for me). Also service needs to have tag `twig.extension`. Otherwise you'll end up having errors such as "Cannot find private service 'assetic' etc"
- setParameter/getParameter are for collecting and returning parameters
- Then I added shortcut methods to my Controller - `setJsVar`
- Twig template requires also handling of those variables, preferably somewhere in the layout level. But that is not included here
- One could you this solution to collect arbitrary template parameters, e.g if you want to assign from another method or whatever
- It would be good idea to clear collected parameters after render

Was that all worth it? I dont know :) Cannot understand why Symfony team chose to make Controller::render final in the first place. But anyway here it is:

TwigEnging class:

```
namespace My\CommonBundle\Component\Templating\MyTwigEngine;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MyTwigEngine extends \Twig_Extension implements EngineInterface
{
    /**
     * @var TwigEngine $twig Original Twig Engine object
     */
    private $twig;
    /**
     * @var array $parameters Collected parameters to be passed to template
     */
    private $parameters = [];


    /**
     * MyTwigEngine constructor.
     *
     * @param TwigEngine $twig
     */
    public function __construct(TwigEngine $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    /**
     * "Collects" parameter to be passed to template.
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @param mixed $value
     *
     * @return static
     */
    public function setParameter($key, $value)
    {
        $this->parameters[$key] = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns "collected" parameter
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getParameter($key, $default = null)
    {
        $val = $this->parameters[$key] ?? $default;

        return $val;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|\Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateReferenceInterface $name
     * @param array $parameters
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws \Twig\Error\Error
     */
    public function render($name, array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->twig->render($name, $this->getTemplateParameters($parameters));
    }

    /**
     * @param string $view
     * @param array $parameters
     * @param Response|null $response
     *
     * @return Response
     * @throws \Twig\Error\Error
     */
    public function renderResponse($view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null)
    {
        return $this->twig->renderResponse($view, $this->getTemplateParameters($parameters), $response);
    }

    /**
     * @param string|\Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateReferenceInterface $name
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function exists($name)
    {
        return $this->twig->exists($name);
    }

    /**
     * @param string|\Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateReferenceInterface $name
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supports($name)
    {
        return $this->twig->supports($name);
    }

    /**
     * @param $name
     * @param array $parameters
     *
     * @throws \Twig\Error\Error
     */
    public function stream($name, array $parameters = array())
    {
        $this->twig->stream($name, $this->getTemplateParameters($parameters));
    }


    /**
     * Returns template parameters, with merged jsVars, if there are any
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getTemplateParameters(array $parameters = [])
    {
        $parameters = array_merge($this->parameters, $parameters);

        return $parameters;
    }
}
```

Decorator service (services.yml):

```
services:
    templating.engine.mytwig:
        decorates: templating.engine.twig
        class: My\CommonBundle\Component\Templating\MyTwigEngine
        # pass the old service as an argument
        arguments: [ '@templating.engine.mytwig.inner' ]
        # private, because you probably won't be needing to access "mytwig" directly
        public:    false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Base controller alteration:

```
namespace My\CommonBundle\Controller;

use My\CommonBundle\Component\Templating\MyTwigEngine;


abstract class Controller extends \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller
{
    /**
    * Allows to set javascript variable from action
    *
    * It also allows to pass arrays and objects - these are later json encoded
    *
    * @param string $name Variable name
    * @param mixed $value - string|int|object|array
    *
    * @return static
    */
    protected function setJsVar($name, $value)
    {
        /** @var MyTwigEngine $templating */
        $templating = $this->getTemplating();
        if (!$templating instanceof MyTwigEngine) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf(
                'Method %s is implemented only by %s', __METHOD__, MyTwigEngine::class
            ));
        }

        $jsvars = $templating->getParameter('jsVars', []);
        $jsvars[$name] = $value;
        $templating->setParameter('jsVars', $jsvars);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns templating service
     * @return null|object|\Twig\Environment
     */
    private function getTemplating()
    {
        if ($this->container->has('templating')) {
            $templating = $this->container->get('templating');
        } elseif ($this->container->has('twig')) {
            $templating = $this->container->get('twig');
        } else {
            $templating = null;
        }

        return $templating;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render a controller from inside Twig like that:

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\YourController::yourAction', { 'args': 'hi' })) }}
```

Documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html)

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what I asked :)

Comment: You question is not very clear, please edit to make it clearer.